# lua_call(S, 0, 0) won't work (attempted to call a string value)?

Tags: c++, lua

So, I wanted to go ahead and add Lua scripting to my C++ game engine, however I can't seem to do it.

I'm watching a video and i have checked out the tiny bit of code and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <Lua Source\lua.hpp>

lua_State* S = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(S);

luaL_loadfile(S, "main.lua");
lua_call(S, 0, 0);
```

The Lua source codes and files are all in my project folder, except for 2 cpp files which were main function (deleted those).

---

And my Lua file looks like this : (and is placed where the Lua source code is.)

```
print("Hello World")
```

---

The error I get looks like this :

**In console :**

```
PANIC : unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to call a string value)
```

This is what the error box that comes up looks like :

(Buttons form left to right : Cancel, Try Again, Ignore)

[Error Box Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6mFL.png)

---

## Edits :

My code now looks like this, adding the `puts(lua_tostring(S, -1));` generated a error message :

```
cannot open main.lua: no such file or directory
```

**Code**

```
lua_State* S = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(S);
luaL_loadfile(S, "main.lua");
puts(lua_tostring(S, -1));
lua_call(S, 0, 0);
```

And my project files like this :

[Image of project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd8Ob.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just misunderstood a tutorial.

Thought he meant that the lua scripts run out of lua's own source code folder...

But, it runs out of your project working directory.

Answer (score 3):

`attempt to call a string value` is triggered by `lua_call` and most probably means that `luaL_loadfile` returned non-zero and left an error message on the stack.

Check the return code of `luaL_loadfile`.

Also, add `puts(lua_tostring(S,-1));` after calling `luaL_loadfile`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, luaL_loadfile returns void? But adding "puts" there, made it give me a error "log" in console : connot open main.lua no such file or directory.